# Erro Exception calling

Tags: powershell

Bom dia

Estou a tentar correr o script powershell https://github.com/the-xentropy/xencrypt/blob/master/xencrypt.ps1 e quer o script quer o ficheiro que estou a tentar encriptar estão na mesma diretoria

os passos que segui foram

```html
Import-Module ./xencrypt.ps1
Invoke-Xencrypt -InFile test.ps1 -OutFile testcrypted.ps1
```

mas deu-me o erro

```html
Invoke-Xencrypt : Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "Não foi possível localizar o ficheiro
'C:\Users\DESKTOP\test.ps1'."
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Xencrypt -InFile test.ps1 -OutFile testcrypted.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-Xencrypt], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException,Invoke-Xencrypt
```

Qual o motivo de tal estar a acontecer?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inclua o resto do diretório junto ao nome do arquivo:

```
$curPath = (Get-Location).Path
$inFile = $curPath + "\test.ps1"
$outFile = $curPath + "\testcrypted.ps1"

Import-Module ./xencrypt.ps1
Invoke-Xencrypt -InFile $inFile -OutFile $outFile
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I do

`PS C:\Users\IEUser\desktop> $curPath = (Get-Location).Path`

`PS C:\Users\IEUser\desktop> $inFile = $curPath + "\test.ps1"`

`PS C:\Users\IEUser\desktop> $outFile = $curPath + "\testcrypted.ps1"`

`PS C:\Users\IEUser\desktop> Import-Module ./xencrypt.ps1`

`PS C:\Users\IEUser\desktop> Invoke-Xencrypt -InFile $file -OutFile $outFile`

but I get

Comment: The variable '$file' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At line:1 char:25
+ Invoke-Xencrypt -InFile $file -OutFile $outFile
+                         ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (file:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined

Comment: There was a typo in the answer... just updated it, check it again.

Comment: getting the error
'Invoke-Xencrypt : Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find file
'C:\users\ieuser\desktop\test.ps1'."
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Xencrypt -InFile $inFile -OutFile $outFile
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-Xencrypt], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException,Invoke-Xencrypt'

Comment: try to run it as administrador

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked